# Spring bean with placeholder create a second bean with different profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Suppose there is a Spring managed bean like this one:

```
@Component
@Profile("prod")
public class MyBean {

    @Value("${x.y.id:-1}")
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Also, the property `x.y.id` does exist in `application-prod.properties` file.

Now, if I want to use the same class to create another managed bean, with a different profile, in a configuration class like this:

```
@Profile("dev")
@Bean
public MyBean myBean() {
    MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
    myBean.setId(10);
    return myBean;
}
```

it doesn't work since `id` field would end up with `-1` value because the placeholder's default value has the final word.

**Question** Is it possible to have a second managed bean in a situation like this?

---

Adding  `x.y.id=10` in application-dev.properties does work for the case above, but not on this one:

```
@Profile("dev")
@Bean
public MyBean myBean() {
    MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
    myBean.setId(10);
    return myBean;
}

@Profile("dev")
@Bean
public MyBean myAnotherBean() {
    MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
    myBean.setId(20);
    return myBean;
}
```

Comment: if you need to set different value then simply add x.y.id=10  in application-dev.properties file

Answer (score 0):

To keep things **homogenous**, you might simply fallback to having an **application-dev.properties file** and set the property there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is "placeholder's default value has the final word..."

However I think the following should work:

You can rewrite `MyBean` class so that it won't use `@Value` and in general will use constructor injection:

```
public class MyBean {

    private final int id;

    public MyBean(int id) {this.id = id;}

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

In this case, the configuration can be defined as follows:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("prod") // also possible to be used per bean
public class MyProductionConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean( @Value("${x.y.id:-1}") int id) {
       return new MyBean(id);
    }
}

@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class MyDevConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
       return new MyBean(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: "placeholder's default value has the final word..." means the second bean has the `id=-1` even though I set the value to 10. Your idea is good, but I cannot change the `MyBean` code.